# How dangerous is mold at the bottom of container with fat

Tags: food-safety, butter, mold

My friends from a farm gave me some clarified butter, about half a liter in a plastic container. I used it for some time, mostly for frying. A couple of days ago I saw mold spots at the bottom of the container. Obviously, this means that butter was not clarified properly and some non-fat components remained at the bottom.

What should I do with the butter? Is it unsafe? Or I am ok to use it if I don't touch a bottom level? Can I transfer untouched butter to another container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would toss it. The only thing where it's generally considered safe to eat around the mold is hard cheeses. In general there will be mold spores in lower concentrations throughout the container, but you only see the areas with high concentration with your bare eyes. The lower concentrations can still make you ill.

Comment: I would further think that mold or any growth at the bottom of processed fat would be an especially bad sign.  It would make my mind immediately go to botulism that thrives in an oxygen free environment.  Mold at the bottom or suspended in untouched fat would scream not processed correctly or safely to me.  On the surface would be more of an air contamination, and though I would likely still discard, I might not run to do so.  What is described I would toss without hesitation.